# Delete row from Vue Js dynamic array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a dynamic table in Vue. I am able to add row properly, but when I try to remove the row, every time it removes the last row by default. 
Even if I hard coded the index number, still same result.

Its been 2 days and I am stuck in this problem. Appreciate any help.

My Template:

```
<div class="box-body">
        <table id="myTable" class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr class="timesheetTableHeader">
            <th style="width: 50rem">Project</th>
            <th style="width: 40rem">Activity</th>
            <th style="width: 20rem">Charge Back</th>
            <th style="width: 10rem">Hours</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <div class="mt-2"></div>
          <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
            <td>
              <mwselect :options="Project"
                        v-model="row.projectName"
              ></mwselect>
            </td>
            <td>
              <mwselect :options="Activity"
                        v-model="row.activity"
              ></mwselect>
            </td>
            <td>
              <mwselect :options="CostCenter"
                        v-model="row.chargeBackCC"
              ></mwselect>
            </td>
            <td>
              <b-form-input type="number"
                            class="pb-1 pt-1"
                            required
                            v-model="row.hours"
                            name="Hours">
              </b-form-input>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a @click="removeElement(index)" style="cursor: pointer">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o pt-1" style="color:red; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
font-size: 1.5em;" title="Delete Line"
                ></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

My Script:

```
 <script>
 var period_name = ''
 var start_date = ''
 var end_date = ''
 var counter = 0
 export default {
components: {
  mwselect
},
data() {
  return {
    Project: projects,
    CostCenter: costcenter,
    Activity: activities,
    rows: []
  }  // return end
},
methods: {
  createLine(index) {
    var elem = document.createElement('tr');
    this.rows.push({
      projectName: "",
      activity: "",
      chargeBackCC: "",
      hours: ""
    })
  },
  removeElement: function (index) {
    alert(index)
    this.rows.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering is not guaranteed unless you put `key` attribute to the for loop. So this change to your  tag must solve the problem:

`<tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index">`

Here is more information about the attribute `key`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you suggestion. I looked further and found that the row is correctly getting removed, but since I am using custom component  "mwselect" in few columns; so this component data is not delete based on the row.. rather the last row component data is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cmertayak,

Adding :key="index" worked and it solved my problem.